# how to add a png to UIAlert button for iphone

Tags: iphone, uialertview

is it possible to change 
1)rectable box to circular
2)add a png to alert box
3)any custom UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UIAlertView is a UIView just like anything else.  You can add whatever you want to it.

I would try setting up a UIAlertView with some blank lines for the message (to give you space to place your own elements) and adding elements the way you would anywhere else:

```
[alertView addSubview:myAwesomeButton];
```

Comment: you mean i have to load other view?? what is that myAwsomebutton?? a png or what